# Oracle: issue with where clause date query

Tags: oracle

Environment : oracle database

I have a table with the column name **DateOfAct** which is of **Date** datatype holds date & time (eg: 2015-10-28 21:21:10 , 2015-10-29 11:09:45)

I need to get records of the day **20-12-2015** starting from                   morning **12:00:00** to night **23:59:59**

```
 select * from my_table 
 where DateOfAct >= to_date('20-12-2015 00:00:00' , 'dd-mm-yyyy 24HH:MI:SS')
 and   DateOfAct <= to_date('20-12-2015 23:59:59', 'dd-mm-yyyy 24HH:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Can you define your specific problem you are addressing?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Try to use DateOfAct BETWEEN '20-12-2015 00:00:00' AND '20-12-2015 23:59:59'

Answer (score 1):

The below code should solve your issue :
In the format for date put **'HH24'** instead of **'24HH'**

```
 select * from my_table 
 where DateOfAct >= to_date('20-12-2015 00:00:00' , 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
 and   DateOfAct <= to_date('20-12-2015 23:59:59', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand any problem here.. But You can try this using between.

```
select * 
from my_table 
where DateOfAct between to_date('20151220000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') 
      and to_date('20151220235959','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

Answer (score 0):

> starting from morning 12:00:00 to night 23:59:59

in your query start date is `to_date('20-12-2015 00:00:00' , 'dd-mm-yyyy 24HH:MI:SS')` - 00:00 (HH24:mi), if you want 12:00 (HH24:mi) is should be `to_date('20-12-2015 12:00:00' , 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')`

```
select * 
  from my_table 
 where DateOfAct between to_date('20-12-2015 12:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
                     and to_date('20-12-2015 23:59:59', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score -2):

The query can be changed like

```
select * from my_table where trunc(DateOfAct)='20-Dec-2015'
```

Explanation:

The function `trunc` removes time part from date and allows you to compare only date value without time.

Comment: Why `trunc(DateOfAct)='20-Dec-2015'`? Why compare a date to a string when you could so easily convert the string into a date - as, in fact, the OP tried to do (albeit with a slightly incorrect format mask)? I've downvoted for this. Correct it and I'll reverse the downvote.